# Is it safe to put dead (non brown) leaves as fertilizer?

Tags: rosemary

I did some cuttings of my rosemary to propagate them.  The bottom leaves were trimmed off from the stems.  Instead of throwing those green leaves away after having a good smell off them, I decided to put them back above the soil of the original plant.

Is there any side effects of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rosemary leaves won't cause any real harm if left on the soil (assuming the plant is in the ground) but they won't do much good either in terms of being a fertilizer. If there are enough of them, they might act as a mulch layer - they can take quite a long time to break down completely. Probably best to add them to a compost heap instead.